# Fork to create similar but different product

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We need to fork our 18 project, 1,000+ file VS2015 C# solution so we can build a similar but different product. Both products will continue to be actively developed. 
Changes might be product-specific (of course, otherwise we'd only need one product) or product-agnostic (e.g. payment processing).

**I'd like improvements made in either product to be available to - but not automatically part of the other.**

I know this could be achieved by manually selecting and merging changesets into the other product, but is there a better way? For example, is there a way developers can mark their check-ins as applicable to both products? Are there any tools I can use to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Even though **Forking** and **Branching** isn't the same! Branching means making a new copy for a new feature and experiments which will be merged to the master later. Forking means making a copy for an independent project.

However, in TFS the branching (from VS or command) is really the only implementation of fork. Detail steps please refer the official MSDN link: [Branch folders and files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425(v=vs.140).aspx)

*Note: You can only branch the source Code, not a Project (Work Items, Queries, Reports) though. Those must be copied into the new one.*